# Flaky Playwright + Google Search Console Test

Tags: python-3.x, playwright-python

I am trying to run a test on Google search console (GSC) with the help of playwright and scraping indexed pages from pages report of the GSC platform.

[google search console pages report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opGYJ.png)

The script is flaky and sometimes, the browser (headless=False) mode doesn't proceed to any further steps after logging into GSC or sometimes I see load event failed errors. I have tried many different ways `wait_for_selector`, `wait_for_timeout` or `wait_for_load_state` but every time the output is unexpected and the test doesn't complete successfully. Wondering, if anyone can share a workaround for me to run the test successfully?

The script is below:

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect

index_count = {}
markets_list = ["/aa/bb/", "/xx/yy/"] 
placeholder_url = "https://www.example.com{}"

def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    
    browser = playwright.firefox.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=5000) #slow_mo=5000
    context = browser.new_context() 

    # Start tracing before creating / navigating a page.
    context.tracing.start(screenshots=True, snapshots=True, sources=True)

    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://search.google.com/search-console/about")
    page.get_by_role("link", name="Start now").nth(1).click()
    page.get_by_role("textbox", name="Email or phone").fill("username")
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Next").click()
    page.get_by_role("textbox", name="Enter your password").fill("password")
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Next").click()
    
    #use a for loop here
    for market in markets_list:
        
        page.get_by_role("button", name="Search property").click()
        page.wait_for_selector("//*[@class='iPVm1b']")
        page.get_by_role("combobox", name="Resource selector").fill(market)
        page.get_by_text(placeholder_url.format(market), exact=True).click()
        page.get_by_role("link", name="Pages", exact=True).click()
        
        indexed_pages_selector = "(//*[@class='nnLLaf vtZz6e'])[2]"
        page.wait_for_selector(indexed_pages_selector, state="visible")
        indexed_pages = page.get_attribute(indexed_pages_selector, name="title")       
        
        page.reload()

        page.wait_for_selector("//input[@class='yNVtPc ZAGvjd Ny5lGc']")
        market_selector = ("//div[@class='Mxgq5c']")
        gsc_market = page.get_attribute(market_selector, name="data-initial-resource-id")[-7:]

        index_count[gsc_market] = indexed_pages
        page.pause()
        page.reload()
    
    # Stop tracing and export it into a zip archive.
    context.tracing.stop(path = "trace.zip")
    
    page.wait_for_timeout(30000)
    # ---------------------
    context.close()
    browser.close()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```